# Is Audio Is Playing? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I've got two activities in my app. The first one (MainActivity.java) has a button to call activity two (Player.java), and the second one has the audio and a stop button.

The main problem I'm facing is:

When I click start second activity from one, it goes to another activity.
As I programmed, it starts audio automatically (I want it to start automatically). I press stop audio stops. Then go back to `MainActivity` call second activity (Player.java) again it works fine. Again it starts audio correctly. Everything is working fine when I press back the audio keeps playing on. (That's what I want).

But, if press back without stopping the audio, and start the second activity (Player.java) again, it starts the audio again without stopping first one. And same track plays two times.

I want to play only one track at once. If any other audio is playing, stop it, when I start that activity again.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        public void clicked(View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button){
              Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, player.class);
              startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.media.*;

public class player extends Activity {
  Button stop;
  MediaPlayer audio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myAudio);
        audio.start();

        public void stop(View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.stop){
                audio.stop();
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myAudio);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call audio.stop in player activity onPause() method when user press the back button. Playing audio is a system service which is independent of your activity life cycle.

So your activity get close stop the audio and when is play again when it launch again.